# dropdown hide image onchange javascript

Tags: javascript, monaca

I'm creating a mobile application on monaca.io. I try to hide image when user select an option from combobox but nothing happens.

```
function setImageVisible(id, visible) {
    var img = document.getElementById(id);
    img.style.visibility = (visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
}
```

Thank you

Comment: do you get your img element or are you already stuck there?

Comment: the code works on Chrome, but when I try it on monaca emulator the code is not working. I have the img element on my html5 document and I just want to hide and put some other code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks ok.
As you states in your comment that it's working on chrome, I think this is not working because of some issue in the monaca emulator.

I'd suggest you try to debug your Code that you can check here:

```
var img = document.getElementById(id);
```

If your `var img` successfully gets the image.